# detect if android app receives it's own referrer

Tags: android, google-play, installation, referrer

I'm develoing an application using google play install referrer, I can receive intent contains referrer using My custom receiver and use this referrer to detect my partner.

But if an android device installs my app then this device installs another app, which also uses install referrer from google play, android will send a broacast intent with referrer info of this new app and my app will receive it so get the wrong referrer info.

Can this scenario happen? and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you get any solution to it?